# Error with value.serializer (Spring Boot and Kafka in docker)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, spring-kafka

If I run spring from fatjar, it uses spring serializer, which works (prescribed in producer settings, package `org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer`), message serialized without error, but
if you try to run spring boot in a container, for some reason the settings don't apply, the standard `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer` works, why is this happening?

```
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String kafkaServer;

    @Value("${spring.kafka.producer.client-id}")
    private String kafkaProducerId;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaServer);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, LongSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, kafkaProducerId);
        return props;
    }
```

logs in docker:

```
value.serializer = class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer
```

Could not instantiate class `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer`

parts of docker-compose:

```
mvc_app:
container_name: mvc_app
build:
  context: zscore_mvc
  dockerfile: /docker/mvc/Dockerfile
ports:
- "8080:8080"
depends_on:
  - db
  - kafka
restart: "no"

zookeeper:
    container_name: zookeeper
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:latest'
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN: 'yes'
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
  kafka:
    image: bitnami/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092
      KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
      ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: 'yes'
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
```

Comment: You need to show the full stack trace - edit the question.

Comment: The `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer` has nothing to do with Apache Kafka at all. More over it is an `abstract` class. Please, search your environment what could set that property wrong way.

Comment: I solved the problem when all the containers and images were destroyed, for some reason the docker didn't want to see the changes in fatjar, this is windows)